# again new query. i am trying to solve this from one hour. please help

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

Query : List the film title and the leading actor for all of 'Julie Andrews' films.

there are three tables

> movie (id, title, yr, score, votes, director)
>
> actor (id, name)
>
> casting (movieid, actorid, ord)

```
select movie.title,actor.name as cont
from movie
join casting on (movie.id=casting.movieid)
join actor on (casting.actorid=actor.id)
where actor.name='Julie andrews'
```

actually i can't get how to find the leading actor.

Comment: How is the leading actor defined? By the 'ord' column?

Comment: actually i dont know what is ord. this is query in sqlzoo.net. please think what it should be?

Comment: So all of you SO question can be summed up to please solve all the queries from http://sqlzoo.net/ and post result? Have you tried reading sqlzoo.net!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost for sure will need a sub query to achieve this one way or another.

```
select movie.title, actor.name
from movie
inner join casting 
    on movie.id = casting.movieid
    and casting.ord = 1 --Assuming this is the cast order flag
inner join actor
    on casting.actorid = actor.id
where movie.id in (
    select movie.id
    from movie 
    inner join casting 
        on movie.id = casting.movieid
        and casting.actorid = {your actorID in this case Julie Andrew's id
 )
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this as you didn't provide an easy way to do so.

If you really wanted to go by name (which could lead to false positive) then you can add an extra join to the in clause sub query.

Comment: Then you should consider mark this as the accepted answer.  Before continuing please try giving this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't use `id` for the key column, use `movieid` and `actorid`. This makes joins easier:

```
select movie.title, lead.name as cont
  from actor
  join casting             using (actorid)
  join movie               using (movieid)
  join casting as leadrole using (movieid)
  join actor   as lead     on (leadrole.actorid = lead.actorid)
 where actor.name = 'Julie andrews'
   and leadrole.ord = 1
```

This assumes that the lead actor's `ord` column is 1. It is also completely untested, so you will probably need to debug it.

Comment: this is not working i think there is mistake in join syntax or anything else?

Comment: I moved `movie` and changed some `using` clauses. Still untested, but give it a go (and don't forget I've assumed the use of `movieid` in the `movie` table and `actorid` in the `actor` table instead of `id`.

Comment: sorry i really can't understand what you have done. be spesific

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific. Judging by your track record of questions, you seriously need to get book on SQL programming and read it cover to cover.

Comment: hey , i do not mean that. sorry... but i didn't understand what you had done. i have the book but it will not teach me how to get practice. i need to practice. thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you need to be more specific. Do you not understand the query, the `using` syntax, the changes to the key columns that I suggested (and assumed in my solution), or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lead role is ord = 1 you can try this out (I didn't test it)

EDIT:

```
select 
      M.title, 
      (select 
            A1.name 
       from 
            casting CI
       join
            actors A1
       on
            A1.id = CI.actorid      
       where 
            CI.movieid = M.id 
       and 
            CI.ord = 1) as LeadingActor 
from 
      movie M
join 
      casting C
on 
      M.id = C.movieid
join 
      actor A 
on 
      C.actorid = A.id
where 
      A.name='Julie andrews'
```

Comment: in some movies there may be situation that julie andrew is not leading actor.

Comment: sorry, forgot a join in subquery. Now I think I fixed it :)

Comment: no problem , see the right answer i have marked. it is working.